# Need to add temp table to this summary query

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following is returning a summary of aged insurance claims amount.

I need to report on which Actual_Dr_name is part of the insurance claims. I am trying to create a temp table that would hold the Dr's, but am not sure where to put that.

```
select  
    Billing_Carrier_Category_Descr, Department_descr, 
    Billing_Carrier_name, Actual_Dr_Name, 
    sum(voucher_balance) as OutstandingN,
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 35 and 40 then voucher_balance else 0 end) as [40 DaysG],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 41 and 50 then voucher_balance else 0 end) as [50 DaysG],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 51 and 60 then voucher_balance else 0 end) as [60 DaysG],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 61 and 70 then voucher_balance else 0 end) as [70 DaysG],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 71 and 80 then voucher_balance else 0 end) as [80 DaysG],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 81 and 90 then voucher_balance else 0 end) as [90 DaysG],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) > 90 and Voucher_Service_date >='01-Jan-2017' then voucher_balance else 0 end) as [90_2017G],
    sum(voucher_balance) * isnull(DeptPercentage,40) / 100 as OutstandingG,
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 35 and 40 then voucher_balance else 0 end) * isnull(DeptPercentage,40) / 100 as [40 DaysN],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 41 and 50 then voucher_balance else 0 end) * isnull(DeptPercentage,40) / 100 as [50 DaysN],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 51 and 60 then voucher_balance else 0 end) * isnull(DeptPercentage,40) / 100 as [60 DaysN],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 61 and 70 then voucher_balance else 0 end) * isnull(DeptPercentage,40) / 100 as [70 DaysN],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 71 and 80 then voucher_balance else 0 end) * isnull(DeptPercentage,40) / 100 as [80 DaysN],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) between 81 and 90 then voucher_balance else 0 end) * isnull(DeptPercentage,40) / 100 as [90 DaysN],
    sum(case when datediff(d,Voucher_Service_date,getdate()) > 90 and Voucher_Service_date >='01-Jan-2017' then voucher_balance else 0 end) * isnull(DeptPercentage,40) / 100 as [90_2017N]
from 
    Vwgenvouchinfo 
left outer join
    (Select 'Dental' DeptName, 37 DeptPercentage
     union 
     Select 'Adult Medicine' DeptName, 24
     union 
     Select 'Family Medicine' DeptName, 24
     union 
     Select 'Family Practice' DeptName, 24
     union 
     Select 'Pediatrics' DeptName, 24
     union 
     Select 'Specialty' DeptName, 41
     union 
     Select 'Ophthamology' DeptName, 41)
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking. Can you explain further?

Comment: I need to pass to a crystal report all the actual_dr as a separate group for reporting intro.

Comment: Is this a view or a stored procedure?

Comment: It's more of a view. It is used in a Crystal report to access the data from the sql server rather than using their designer.

Comment: how about using table valued function?

Comment: that could be good.